# I need help on this Java inheritance program

Tags: java, inheritance

The problem that my code is based on is found on the following website:

http://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problem.jsp?category=Building+Java+Programs%2C+3rd+edition%2FBJP3+Chapter+9&problem=bjp3-9-e11-FilteredAccount

So basically, my code works for the boolean values, but for the following method: **percentFiltered**, my code goes berserk.

When submitting my code through the link provided above, this is what ***my output*** is:

> percentFiltered (initial): 0.0
>
> process(0)   process return value: true   percentFiltered: 100.0
>   super.process called: false
>
> process(0)   process return value: true   percentFiltered: 200.0

However, this is the ***correct*** ***output***:

> percentFiltered (initial): 0.0
>
> process(0)   process return value: true   percentFiltered: 100.0
>   super.process called: false
>
> process(0)   process return value: true   percentFiltered: 100.0

So notice that I am 100.0 off of the expected answer (I got 200.0, they got 100.0). So now I am stumped. I'm still quite new to this inheritance thing so I have no idea where I went wrong. Here is the code that I wrote and submitted:

```
public class FilteredAccount extends Account {
    private int nonzeroTransCnt = 1;
    private int zeroTransCnt;

    public FilteredAccount(Client c) {
        super(c);
    }

    public double percentFiltered() {
        return zeroTransCnt / nonzeroTransCnt * 100.0;
    }

    public boolean process(Transaction t) {
        if (t.value() == 0) {
            zeroTransCnt++;
            super.__processCalled = false;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            nonzeroTransCnt++;
            super.__processCalled = true;
            return t.value() > -100 && t.value() < 1000000;
        }
    }
}
```

If you click on the link above, they have an extended file called **Account**.
Thanks in advance, if you are able to help me.

Comment: Rather than post a link, you may wish to instead explain in your question the details of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your formula is incorrect. You need to divide by the total number of transactions, not the number of unfiltered transactions. You've also got an issue where you're doing int division before casting to doubles.

```
    public double percentFiltered() {
        return (100.0 * zeroTransCnt) / (nonzeroTransCnt + zeroTransCnt);
    }
```

On another note, you can simplify process by using super. And you're probably not supposed to set the flag directly.

```
public boolean process(Transaction t) {
    if (t.value() == 0) {
        zeroTransCnt++;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        nonzeroTransCnt++;
        return super.process(t);
    }
}
```

Edit:

Another problem is that you're setting nonzeroTransCnt to 1 initially. While it does stop the divide by zero errors for the initial call, it gives incorrect results.

```
private int nonzeroTransCnt;
```

You'll probably want to add a separate check for the initial call.

```
    public double percentFiltered() {
        if ((nonzeroTransCnt + zeroTransCnt) == 0) {return 0.0;} //for initial call
        return (100.0 * zeroTransCnt) / (nonzeroTransCnt + zeroTransCnt);
    }
```

Comment: I tried it, but now, the expected output says 100.0, but based on the formula you provided, my output was 50.0? Everything else is still correct though.

Comment: Where are you getting this expected output from? It's not in the link you posted.

Comment: @user Oh I see the problem. You're also setting nonzeroTransCnt to 1 initially instead of 0.

Comment: Ah, I see! But what's really confusing me is that after I take away the 1 and do: nonzeroTransCnt; it gives me a NaN output. :/

Comment: That's because they're calling it before they give you any transactions for some reason, so you'll have to add a seperate check for that. See my second version.

Comment: Ah! So that's what I was missing! I thought so, too but was unsure. Thank you so much for your help! I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @user then at least +1 the answer :-)